# C email with smtp authorization CURL

Tags: c, linux, eclipse-cdt

I try to make C email function using SMTP authorization according to this example: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-authzid.html

When i try to compile this example i get an error: 'Symbol 'CURLOPT_SASL_AUTHZID' could not be resolved'

Rocky Linux 8.6
Curl 7.61.1
Eclipse CDT

Answer (score 0):

Added in CURL 7.66.0. Via Rocky packages last supported is just 7.61.1
Need to use the older example or update Curl.